# how to read/understand azure worker role thread count performance counter

Tags: azure, threadpool, azure-worker-roles

we are investigating a possible thread pool starvation issue we have on one of our azure work role instance. I am trying to understand how to read the "thread count" performance counter we get from the diagnostic log. Does the max and min count should remain consistent ? I am seeing the count for min and max count kept growing as the time goes, does that mean we have a problem with managing threads in our worker application?

The thing that prompts us to look into possible threading issue was that we got a lot of exception thrown by Azure push notification client library saying it is unable to obtain thread from thread pool